# Detect and remove blank pages in PDF file with perl

Tags: perl, pdf

Is there a reliable way to detect blank pages with a perl script? I tried to do it with to following script by using the getPageText method. If I do it like that, pages which only contain graphics without text are also recognized as blank pages.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CAM::PDF;
my $filename=$ARGV[0];
my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($filename) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";
my $pages = $doc->numPages();
print $pages;

$content=$doc->getPageText(1);
print "length".length($content);
if(length($content)==0)
{
  print "File is empty";
}

foreach my $p ( 1 .. $doc->numPages() ) {
    my $str = $doc->getPageText($p);
    $str =~ m/[[:alnum:]]+/ms );  # actually returned text
    print "Result text:".qq($str);
 }
```

Is there another approach to find blank pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to reliable detect blank pages.

However, I did this in the past:

I used pdftk to burst the pdf into one page pdf document.
If one of the pdfs size is very low, it does not contain images.
If pdftotext returns empty string it does not contain text.
Use pdftk to assemble all good pdfs into one.

I hope it will will helps you.

Comment: I hope you realize this is very dangerous? A ten by ten pixel image is probably not going to make any difference in the file size so you're going to miss that. How about a page that contains only a blank character somewhere (which would be returned as text but wouldn't mark the page). How about a simple page background drawn with vector art? That would take about 40 characters or so to draw but wouldn't show up in any way... There be dragons!

Comment: I know. I did not said it is a good or reliable method but I do not have better. There are a lot of different pdf out there :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you use the getPageContentTree method instead of getPageText, you can get a content stream containing all of the objects on the page, including images.  Check the length of the value for the "content" hash key, and if that equals 0, you've got a truly blank page.

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $filename="testBook.pdf";
my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($filename) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";
my $pages = $doc->numPages();

my $i = 1;

while ($i <= $pages) {
    my $contentTree = $doc->getPageContentTree($i);

    my $content = $contentTree->{"content"};
    my $length = length($content);

    if ($length == 0) {
        print "page $i is blank!" ## delete it, log it to a list of blanks, etc.
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this might be a little safer but not much. I've seen many PDF files that have all kinds of things in the content stream but still would render a completely blank page. The example I gave of having only spaces on the page is one, but there are plenty of pages where you have only save / restores or clipping masks or ...

Comment: Fair enough - you're right that there could be cases where it does not detect and remove a page that visually appears blank, but has some "invisible" content in the content stream.  But that page isn't really blank, is it?  The benefit to this approach is more in the fact that it will not remove any pages that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: You're absolutely right - it really depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, which is what I was trying to indicate with my comment. If you're in a publishing workflow for example (where most of my experience is) and you're trying to weed out whether people have sent you empty advertisements, it's really important to know whether something will be printed on that page or not. Hence my stressing the need to use a "safe" algorithm. (or at least realise what you might be getting yourself into.